# 'Could not resolve type with token 010001d6 from typeref (expected class 'NavigationItemReselectedEventArgs' in assembly '')' encountered

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Does anyone encounter this error after upgrading from C# Xamarin.Forms 4.8 to 5.0.0.2515?

**System.TypeLoadException:** 'Could not resolve type with token 010001d6 from typeref (expected class 'NavigationItemReselectedEventArgs' in assembly '')'

The error occurs on this line:

bottomNavigationView.NavigationItemReselected += BottomNavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;

Or is there a workaround? if the line above is deprecated in Xamarin.Forms 5.X?

When I revert back the xamarin.forms version to 4.8, application works well.

Please help. Thanks

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Please check the nuget packages `Xamarin.Forms` on each platform project, and make sure the versions are the lastest and the same.

**2.** If the method above does not work, try to create a new project and copy the sample code into it, and then try again.